# Having a problem adding a throws clause to a toString method header

Tags: java, exception, checked

can someone help?  I'm a CS student working on a project in java for class.  We need to create a checked exception that's thrown in a LinkedQueue class.  All that is fine.  In my class above the LinkedQueue we need to acknowledge the exception and not handle it.  So for each method in the class that calls the LinkedQueue method I added 'throws EmptyQueueException'.  It works except for the toString method.  When I add the throws clause I get an error that says

> "overrider java.lang.Object.toString"

and

> Exception EmptyQueueException in not compatible with throws clause in Object.toString.

Any ideas/help?

thanks so much

Comment: You cannot to that. Your class overrides the toString method, meaning that you cannot change its signature. That includes exceptions.

Comment: It has to do with the `toString()` signature. Since it's an override it needs to remain in the same form as the method it is overriding. This includes return type, access level, parameters, and throw declarations.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The contract of the `Object#toString()` method guarantees that it won't throw any checked exceptions, and since anything that's an `Object` (everything) has to meet this contract, you can't add a checked exception. `toString()` should *never* throw an exception of any kind anyway, because it's used in thousands of places all throughout applications and should be "safe" to call.

Comment: So what do I do?  I asked my professor if I can change it to an unchecked exception and the answer was no.  It's being thrown in the .front() method of the linkedqueue and I need to call that in the toString if I want to know what I'm printing!  Can I acknowledge this somewhere else to cover the toString or handle it in a different way?  Thanks

Comment: @WantaghMomma then you'll have to [catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) and handle the exception instead of throwing it from the method.

Comment: @WantaghMomma In fact, `toString()` is often called when an exception is thrown to provide additional context details. It would be a terribale idea to throw an exception from a `catch` block since **the current exception will be aborted and its context lost**. Instead, return an empty string or a default value. This will safe a lot of time.

Comment: @WantaghMomma You shouldn't be unconditionally calling `front()` or whatever method. Instead, check to see whether your queue is empty first. We might be able to help if you included the actual code of your `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.